# Как удалить Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

Хочу удалить Tomcat с компьютера (mac). Нигде не нашёл, как это сделать. Подскажите!

Comment: как вы его ставили?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/196136/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы удалить Tomcat достаточно удали директорию в которую он был распакован. Предварительно его остановить запустив `shutdown.sh`